# Which machine learning model works well when the feature of one class overlap with another class?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

with respect to this [training data set plot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iNFDOw_MM3s1vYSmBjQ0BJ2D3QFpQyvX/view?usp=sharing), which machine learning model suites well for this. As most of the column values of one class overlaps with another class.

Comment: I don't think that the plot helps to understand the separability of the data. You should plot a scatted plot (feature1 vs feature2) coloring the sample by class.

Comment: @Roberto Please find the scattered plot [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzVOHatMqV-fKQIhqcdOHdaK45gOXFXj/view?usp=sharing] of training data set

Comment: thanks, that helps. I will post an answer

Answer (score 4):

Just a friendly reminder. Stack-overflow is a platform for question concerning programming. Your question is off topic.

Looking at the scatter plot, I would say that with a logistic regression you can already achieve some results. Clearly your data are not perfectly separable in the two-dimensional space. You will have an error that is different from zero by design.

For better results you have some options:

1) design better feature. The fact that the samples for the two classes overlap is a sign that the discriminative power of the feature is limited. You could consider to find better measurements that characterize your samples.

2) Use a SVM with a kernel that maps your problem in a space with higher dimensions. The fact that the samples are not separable in the two-dimensional space could be easily solved in a high dimensional one. The kernel of SVM (e.g. polynomial, Gaussian,...) maps your point in an higher space separating the data in that space.

Comment: @Dinesh please if my answer has been helpful, upvote it ;)

Comment: Since you do think that the question is off-topic (and I happen to agree), I kindly suggest you follow the relevant [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) (refrain from answering); plus, OP cannot upvote due to not enough reputation (a request for *accepting* the answer would be more understandable here)...

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for the feedback, I didn't remember the reputation constraints for upvoting. About answering, I considered enough to advise him to pay more attention to the topic of the question since he is a new user.